# How to migrate a unsharded collection to sharded collection

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

How to migrate an existing **unsharded** collection to a **sharded** one, while using Cosmos DB with mongo api ?

Comment: Simply use command `sh.shardCollection(namespace, key)` depending on size of existing data, it may take a while.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, WernFried, will this option for existing collections ? It gives me error "collection already exists"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is to copy the data from the first collection to a new sharded collection. You can use mongoexport/import or whatever tool you want to do this.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I have tried it in Compass with a small collection and it worked fine. However, how do we do the same if the data is huge. Will it support the same ?

Comment: For massive amounts of data I'd probably use Spark or Kafka. Here's a doc that can help get you started. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/migrate-databricks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for delay, I just tested it on my system with a collection of 30 Million documents:

```
db.getSiblingDB('data').getCollection("sessions.unsharded").getShardDistribution()
Collection data.sessions.unsharded is not sharded.

db.getSiblingDB('data').getCollection("sessions.unsharded").estimatedDocumentCount()
29073126

sh.shardCollection('data.sessions.unsharded', {tsi: 1, si: 1})
{
    "collectionsharded" : "data.sessions.unsharded",
    "ok" : 1,
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1646225768, 20018)
}
```

It takes some time till collection is evenly distributed, but after some time

```
db.getSiblingDB('data').getCollection("sessions.unsharded").getShardDistribution()

Shard shard_03 at shard_03/d-mipmdb-sh1-03.swi.srse.net:27018,d-mipmdb-sh2-03.swi.srse.net:27018
 data : 87.04MiB docs : 28300 chunks : 3
 estimated data per chunk : 29.01MiB
 estimated docs per chunk : 9433

Shard shard_01 at shard_01/d-mipmdb-sh1-01.swi.srse.net:27018,d-mipmdb-sh2-01.swi.srse.net:27018
 data : 99.08MiB docs : 18893 chunks : 2
 estimated data per chunk : 49.54MiB
 estimated docs per chunk : 9446

Shard shard_02 at shard_02/d-mipmdb-sh1-02.swi.srse.net:27018,d-mipmdb-sh2-02.swi.srse.net:27018
 data : 88.13MiB docs : 28335 chunks : 3
 estimated data per chunk : 29.37MiB
 estimated docs per chunk : 9445

Shard shard_04 at shard_04/d-mipmdb-sh1-04.swi.srse.net:27018,d-mipmdb-sh2-04.swi.srse.net:27018
 data : 96.24GiB docs : 29073126 chunks : 3072
 estimated data per chunk : 32.08MiB
 estimated docs per chunk : 9463

Totals
 data : 96.5GiB docs : 29148654 chunks : 3080
 Shard shard_03 contains 0.08% data, 0.09% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 3KiB
 Shard shard_01 contains 0.1% data, 0.06% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 5KiB
 Shard shard_02 contains 0.08% data, 0.09% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 3KiB
 Shard shard_04 contains 99.72% data, 99.74% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 3KiB
```

So, I don't understand why you get this error. Maybe caused by Cosmos DB API

Comment: Thanks Wernfried for following up and doing the test. Was the test done above on Cosmos DB (using Mongo API) or was it a native Mongo DB, just confirming.

Comment: I run it on my native locally installed MongoDB

Comment: Ok, I suppose this has to do with the Cosmos DB Mongo API, doesn't support sharding existing collection using the mongo command

Comment: Then it looksl like you need to copy the data. However, I don't know how to shard a non-existing collection.

Comment: Within cosmos db , it gives option to provide shard keys upfront, while creation of the collection itself. If you miss creating them, we end up here :)